# Typescript transpiled code "*.js" missing in imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-2020

I have the following code (example):

User.ts

```
...
import { UserFavoriteRoom } from "./UserFavoriteRoom.js";
import { Room } from "./Room.js";
import { Reservation } from "./Reservation.js";
import { Message } from "./Message.js";
import { Review } from "./Review.js";
...
```

But when typescript transpiles the code into javascript, the result looks like this:

User.js

```js
...
import { UserFavoriteRoom } from "./UserFavoriteRoom";
import { Room } from "./Room";
import { Reservation } from "./Reservation";
import { Message } from "./Message";
import { Review } from "./Review";
...
```

As you can see the `.js` is missing in the imports, and it is a huge problem because when I try to run the code this happens:

```
'Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module: 'UserFavoriteRoom' imported from User.js
```

If I manually append the `.js` to `userFavoriteRoom` (the import inside the User.js file) for example, then the error goes away and another error like that happens with another import that doesn't have the `.js` at the end of the import.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": [
      "src"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
  },
}
```

And my package.json: (I am using node 18.16.0)

```json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build tsconfig.json",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.7.5",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "graphql": "^16.7.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

What can I do to append the `.js` to the imports in the transpiled code automatically?

Comment: Just wanna say it's quite strange. I have roughly the same configuration, and I am required to add `.js` to typescript import statements, and they _do_ get retained in the output.

Comment: @Evert I don't know why, but it suddenly started to work as expected, the only thing I remember I did was to try some compilerOptions, didn't work, then undo the changes, and it magically started worked as expected (even when I just did that before). I want to think that somehow something was cached and all I can recommend for now who has the same problem is to restart vscode, or even the computer.

Comment: Not super shocked! Sounds like you can close this question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `allowJs` compiler flag to your Typescript configuration:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "allowJs": true
  },
}
```

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs